# How to Extract Multiple words from a string using IndexOf and substring Java?

Tags: java, string, substring, indexof

I have a file i imported through system, Now i am stuck. Using while loops and if statements, and WITHOUT the help of the Split() method, How could i first, Read the file, line by line with the scanner? Then second how could i pull the words out one by one, As i pull out one word, A variable, countWords has to increase by one, say there is 5 words in a string, I would need to run through the loop 5 times and countWords would become 5.
This is the code i have so far, Kind of crappy.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

class Assignmentfive
{
private static final String String = null;

 public static void main(String[] args) throws              FileNotFoundException
 {
 Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File("asgn5data.txt"));

int educationLevel = 0;
String fileRead = "";
int wordCount = 0;

while (scan.hasNext() && !fileRead.contains("."))
{
  fileRead = scan.nextLine();

  int index = fileRead.indexOf(" ");
  String strA = fileRead.substring(index);

  System.out.print(strA);
  wordCount++;

 }
```

There is more to my code, however it is just a few calculations commented out.
Thanks!

Comment: If you can't use `String.split()`, would you be allowed to use a tokenizer?

Comment: unfortunately, that is a no as well. The teach said " They don't teach you to program"

Comment: I think you are on the right track.  You can use `String.indexOf()` to find each end of word, and then substring that word off.

Comment: So make a new line called String.indexOf()? or use the one i currently have to find the end of each word?

Comment: Please format your code. For just reading lines, unless required to use a `Scanner`, change to `BufferedReader`. Scanner is a beast, performance-wise. Since a line can contain multiple words, you need to use the [`indexOf(int ch, int fromIndex)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf%28int,%20int%29) method.

Comment: Cant switch to the other reader :(.

Comment: @Andreas I have done that, It returns the, (My first sentence is the cat is black.) Now how would i get it then to go and return cat? Any tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I would refactor your `while` loop to correctly extract, print, and count all words in a sentence:

```
while (scan.hasNext()) {
    int wordCount = 0;
    int numChars = 0;
    fileRead = scan.nextLine();

    // Note: I add an extra space at the end of the input sentence
    //       so that the while loop will pick up on the last word.
    if (fileRead.charAt(fileRead.length() - 1) == '.') {
        fileRead = fileRead.substring(0, fileRead.length() - 1) + " ";
    }
    else {
        fileRead = fileRead + " ";
    }
    int index = fileRead.indexOf(" ");
    do {
        String strA = fileRead.substring(0, index);
        System.out.print(strA + " ");
        fileRead = fileRead.substring(index+1, fileRead.length());
        index = fileRead.indexOf(" ");
        wordCount++;
        numChars += strA.length();
    } while (index != -1);

    // here is your computation.
    if (wordCount > 0) {
        double result = (double)numChars / wordCount;  // average length of words
        result = Math.pow(result, 2.0);                // square the average
        result = wordCount * result;                   // multiply by number of words
        System.out.println(result);                    // output this number
    }
}
```

I tested this code by hard-coding the string `fileRead` to be your first sentence `The cat is black.`.  I got the following output.

**Output:**

```
The
cat
is
black
```

Comment: Thats perfect! Now how could i make it look only at the first line in the file, then do all the calculations, then move on to the second line?

Comment: Your outer `while` loop is already going through the input file line by line.  If all you want to do is to print out each word, from each sentence, and keep a total count of all words, then you are done.  If you have other requirements, let me know and I will try to address them.

Comment: I have to get the words from a sentence, printed on their own line. Get the average length of the words from that sentence, Square the average and then multiply the average by the number of words from that sentence. And then repeat for each sentence in the file.

Comment: Wow. you are amazing. You are a god among men. Thank you so much dude. Im going to spend alot of time analyzing your code so i can learn from this. Thanks again man.

Comment: I added a `double` cast in the calculation, q.v. the updated code.  Other than this, it looks fine.